# Онлайн чи он-лайн?

Tags: правопис, разом-дефіс-окремо

Часто помічаю, що слово "онлайн" пишуть у різних статтях або через дефіс, або разом. Шукала правопис цього слова в інтернеті. У [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD) написано "онлайн", але в інших словниках не знайшла відповіді. 
То як писати правильно "онлайн" чи "он-лайн"?

Comment: У яких статтях ви знайшли через дефіс? У яких словниках шукали? Логічно, наприклад, припустити, що у Грінченка (1907) цього слова нема. :-)

Comment: @bytebuster, підтримую запитання bytebuster. Варто зазначати приклади місць, у яких Ви бачити разом і дефісно, у самому тексті запитання (і в яких сучасних словниках Ви шукали або що Ви не знаєте, де знайти сучасні словники).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Старіший орфографічний словник [«Словники України on-line»](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) (2008) містить написання «**он‑ла́йн**».

В той же час трішки новіший тлумачний «Словник української мови» в 20 томах, хоч і не має ще в інтернеті опублікованих томів на літеру «О», але містить написання «**онлайн**» (і лише таке) в прикладах до 6-го тому (2015):

> [ІНТЕРНЕ́Т-КА́МЕРА](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/?page=1239&wordid=200685), и, *ж[іночий рід]*. <…> *У Дубні встановлено інтернет-камери, завдяки яким можна стежити за життям міста в режимі **онлайн*** (з газ.).
>
> ---
>
> [ІНТЕРНЕ́Т-НОВИ́НИ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/?page=1239&wordid=209566), и́н, *мн[ожина]* (*одн[ина]* інтерне́т-нови́на, и, *ж[іночий рід]*). <…> *Інтернет-новини в режимі **онлайн***; *Незалежні інтернет-новини*.
>
> ---
>
> [КА́СКО](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/?wordid=171297&page=1298), *невідм[інюване]*, *с[ередній рід]*, *фін*. <…> *Розрахунок вартості поліса автомобільного каско можна зробити в офісі вибраної страхової компанії та в режимі **онлайн** за допомогою автоматичного розрахунку* (з мови реклами).

Хоч такий висновок зарано робити на основі лише двох словників, але складається враження, що маємо тенденцію переходу від написання «он-лайн» (чи неусталеного написання) до написання «онлайн» (можливо, подібно до того, як це [відбувалося в англійській мові](//english.stackexchange.com/a/42046)). Що однак не обовʼязково означає неможливість дефісного написання. Англійською, наприклад, дозволені обидва варіанти: «[on-line](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/on-line#English)» і «[online](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/online#English)» (причому, що цікаво, перший ми бачимо прямо у назві словника 2008 року, а другий — словника 2015) — хоч друге і вживається в наш час значно частіше.

Англійсько-українсько-англійський словник наукової мови (фізика і споріднені науки) О. Кочерги і Є. Мейнаровича (2010) також [містить](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD&dicts=5&filter_lines=on) написання «онла́йн». Також деякі словники фіксують «онла́йн-…» як першу частину складених слів (наприклад, «онла́йн-словни́к») і навіть прикметник «онла́йновий», що ще більше ставить під сумнів доречність дефіса.

Answer (score 3):

СУМ-20 вже маїть цього слова, де пишиться разом.

> [ОНЛА́ЙН](//sum20ua.com/Entry/search/%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD), *інформ*.
>
> 1. *присл*. У режимі реального часу; перебуваючи, спілкуючись у мережі “Інтернет”. *Книги доступні для читання онлайн і для завантаження у відповідному форматі* (з навч. літ.); *Грайте онлайн безкоштовно і без реєстрації!* (з мови реклами).
> 2. *у знач. ім., род. у, ч*. Перебування, спілкування в режимі реального часу в мережі “Інтернет”. *Частка онлайну становила 0,5 % в обороті компанії* (з газ.); П*рисутність політиків в онлайні є чудовим безкоштовним майданчиком для привернення уваги ЗМІ та електорату* (із журн.).
> 3. *у знач. прикм., невідм*. Те саме, що **онла́йновий**. *Електронні заяви абітурієнтів, подані в режимі онлайн за допомогою мережі “Інтернет”, будуть ураховуватися приймальними комісіями ВНЗ і мати таку ж силу, як і їхні паперові копії* (з газ.).

Са́ме слово наче підпадаїть під таке правило [правописа 2019](https://files.nas.gov.ua/PublicMessages/Documents/0/2021/01/210118223223523-1428.pdf#page=48):

> § 35. Загальні правила правопису складних слів
>
> Правопис слів разом і з дефісом
>
> 5. Разом пишемо
>
>    2. слова з першими часто вживаними іншомовними частинами на голосний і приголосний: *абро-, авіа-, авто-* (‘само’, ‘автоматичний’), *агро-, аеро-, аква-, алко-, арт-, астро-, аудіо-, біо-, боди-, боді-* (перед голосним), *веб-, геліо-, гео-, гідро-, дендро-, екзо-, еко-, економ-, етно-, євро-, зоо-, ізо-, кібер-, мета-, метео-, моно-, мото-, нарко-, нео-, онко-, палео-, пан-, пара-, поп-, прес-, псевдо-, смарт-, соціо-, теле-, фіто-,
>       фолк-* (*фольк-*), *фоно-* та ін.